# quantifier elimination in z3

Tags: z3, simplify, quantifiers

I am trying to get z3 to simplify the formula ∃u.(u=x)∧(u=y) to (x=y).
I tried:

```
(declare-sort A)
(declare-const x A)
(declare-const y A)
(assert (exists ((u A)) (and (= u x) (= u y))))
(apply (then ctx-solver-simplify qe))
```

but this does not simplify the formula. Why? And how should I simplify this formula?

Answer (score 0):

Z3 is unable to make such quantifier elimination.  Using Redlog of Reduce we obtain:

[image]